# disable button with two condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, laravel-5

l have a problem with jquery to disable the button that depends on two conditions.the first condition that the user must select one option.the second condition that the user must upload a file.I try to write the code for the first condition but does not work well

here is the code for the form to upload a file

```
<form action="{{route('filestest')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     {{csrf_field()}}

    <input id="file-id"type="file" name="file1" ></input>
```

this is the code for  a button that I want to disable it if the two condition invalid

```
<button  class="enableOnInput"type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitorder" disabled="disabled">send file</button>
```

and this is the code for the list that enables user to select one option

```
    <select id="select-id" name="select-name" >
    <option value="" selected="selected" ></option>
   <option value="cr">Course Report. </option>
    <option value="st" >Students' Sample of Test (Final Exam).(Highest)</option>
</select>
```

here is the javascript code to disable the send file button for the first condition only.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
  $('#select-id').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val() == ''){
$('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled',true);
    }else{
      $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your whole code can be rewritten `$('#select-id').keyup(() => $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', !$(this).val().length))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check and make sure that both conditions. (also do note that you should use `change()` and not `keyup()`)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#select-id, #file-id').change(function() {
    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', !($('#select-id option:selected').val() != '' && $('#file-id').val() != ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="file-id" type="file" name="file1"></input>

<button class="enableOnInput" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitorder" disabled="disabled">send file</button>

<select id="select-id" name="select-name">
    <option value="" selected="selected" ></option>
   <option value="cr">Course Report. </option>
    <option value="st" >Students' Sample of Test (Final Exam).(Highest)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the event listener to `change()` event not `keyup`, the keyup listens for keyboard input from user and is not applicable for select

```js
$(function(){
  $('#select-id, #file-id').change(function(){
  
    $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled',($('#select-id').val() == '' || $('#file-id').val() == ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-id" name="select-name" >
    <option value="" selected="selected" ></option>
   <option value="cr">Course Report. </option>
    <option value="st" >Students' Sample of Test (Final Exam).(Highest)</option>
</select>

 <input id="file-id" type="file" name="file1" ></input>

<button  class="enableOnInput"type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitorder" disabled="disabled">send file</button>
```

Comment: I try this, and it is work thank you very much. now I want to write a code for the second condition

Comment: check the edit, I have changed the listener to select both fields and not only the select, the disable the button based on both fields values.